# Hetzner 1 Public IP + Proxmox + OPNSense

Tags: iptables, proxmox, hetzner, opnsense

I have the following problem, I have a dedicated server in Hetzner with 1 public IP, I must install a Proxmox, a virtual machine with OPNSense to use as a router... and the other virtual machines connect through said router.

I have my /etc/network/interfaces as follows from Proxmox:

```
# network interface settings; autogenerated
# Please do NOT modify this file directly, unless you know what
# you're doing.
#
# If you want to manage parts of the network configuration manually,
# please utilize the 'source' or 'source-directory' directives to do
# so.
# PVE will preserve these directives, but will NOT read its network
# configuration from sourced files, so do not attempt to move any of
# the PVE managed interfaces into external files!

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo inet6 loopback

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
        address 78.46.177.76/27
        gateway 78.46.177.65
        up route add -net 78.46.177.76 netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 78.46.177.65 dev enp4s0
        post-up sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
        post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s0 -p tcp -m multiport ! --dport 22,8006 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1
        post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s0 -p udp -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1
# route 78.46.177.76/27 via 78.46.177.65

iface enp4s0 inet6 static
        address 2a01:4f8:121:4c9::2/64
        gateway fe80::1

iface eth0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.0/24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.1.1/24' -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.1.1/24' -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet manual
        ovs_type OVSBridge
```

download OPNSense create a new virtual machine, then in configuration use:

WAN: vtnet0 ip 192.168.1.1/24

For a WAN enter the new wan IPv4 upstream gateway address: 192.168.1.0

Do you want to use the gateway as the ipv4 name server too? AND

IPV6 DHCP: Y

DHCP FOR WAN: N

ok after this, I must do a pfctl -d so that the proxmox can see the opnsense...

I install a virtual machine with Windows 7, I add the data to the network card:
192.168.1.2
255.255.255
192.168.1.1

1.1.1.1

With this I can enter http://192.168.1.1 (OPNSense)

I change to port 9000 and set it to HTTP and disable HTTP_REFERER

With this I can now access OPNSense from outside.

Now... in OPNSense I open the port for example 7775 and run a python on Windows 7 with a hello world... when I want to enter from the outside... I can't but the mv can browse the internet.

But if I change the gateway to 192.168.1.0 in the Windows 7 virtual machine, it can browse the Internet, but I cannot access it from outside to port 7775.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You also need to create a LAN network in OPNSense https://www.wundertech.net/how-to-install-opnsense-in-proxmox/

Comment: Even when leaving out Proxmox and OPNSense I can see several things that don't add up in the network definitions: `iface eth0 inet manual`: Does this serve any purpose? If not, why is it here? Ditto for **vmbr1**: What purpose does that one serve? It also doesn't seem to be relevant for the problem at hand. However, the real problem is the address assignment to vmbr0: What you have set as an interface address is in reality the address of a class C network (the correct definition has to be `address 192.168.1.1/24`).

Comment: Also what does **vtnet0** reference? There doesn't seem to be an obvious relation to any of the previous definitions. So now by making an educated guess, your problems seem to stem from your referencing the network address of your virtual LAN which is inevitably going to invite trouble. To solve this, you need to completely overhaul your address assignments. And as far as the address assignments for the vNIC under Win 7, which item is which? That's not obvious especially since I cannot visualize the dialog layout right now.